# Convert integer to byte array and byte array to Integer

Tags: java, int, arrays

I have 2 methods that one of them converts the Integer to byte array and the other one converts byte array to integer.
But both of them when I define the length of byte array less than 4, I get an exception.
How can I fix both of my methods.

```
public class Test {

public Test() {

}

public static int getIntegerFromByte(byte[] byteArr) {

        return (byteArr[0] ) << 24 | (byteArr[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (byteArr[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (byteArr[3] & 0xFF);

}

public byte[] getByteArrayFromInteger(int intValue ,int byteArrSize) {


            ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteArrSize);
            wrapped.putInt(intValue);
            byte[] byteArray = wrapped.array();
            return byteArray;

}

public static void main (String []args) throws IOException {

    Test app = new Test();

    byte [] b = app.getByteArrayFromInteger(1, 3);
    System.out.println("Length of Byte:\t"+ b.length+ "\n Value: \t"+ getIntegerFromByte(b));
    byte [] byteArr = new byte[3];
    byteArr[0] = 0;
    byteArr[1] = 0;
    byteArr[2] = 1;

    System.out.println("Length of Byte:\t"+ byteArr.length+ "\n Value: \t"+ getIntegerFromByte(byteArr));

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Come on, spill the beans. Which exception? Also, is the endianness of int well-defined in Java, i.e. is your code portable?

Comment: Integer's occupy 32-bit.

Comment: @Cruncher: I think someone already gave the answer. The OP has a problem when there are less than 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is of 4 bytes. From the javadoc for `ByteBuffer.putInt()`

> **Writes four bytes** containing the given int value, in the current byte
>   order, into this buffer at the current position, and then increments
>   the position by four.

and throws:

> BufferOverflowException - If there are fewer than four bytes remaining
>   in this buffer

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you were trying to write a 32-bit (4 byte) `int` value to a 3 byte array. Your `getIntegerFromByte` expects an array of at least 4 bytes.

Try

```
byte[] b = app.getByteArrayFromInteger(1, 4);
```

Comment: But I want to change my integer in to 3 bytes.

Comment: You will have to write custom functions which writes/reads a 24-bit value. 24-bit `int` value is non-standard. The only library I know which does this is mine, but I wouldn't uses it just for this simple example.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to fact that for conversion you are using byte array of length four, if you gives less size it will give exception relevant to out of bound....

Answer (score 0):

try like this :-

```
byte [] b = app.getByteArrayFromInteger(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible to write it something like this to get rid of the dependencies of length?

```
public static int getIntegerFromByte(byte[] byteArr) {
    return getIntegerFromByte(0, byteArr);

}

public static int getIntegerFromByte(int sum, byte[] byteArr) {
    if (byteArr.length == 0)
        return sum;
    sum = (sum << 8) + (byteArr[0] & 0xFF);
    return (getIntegerFromByte(sum, Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArr, 1, byteArr.length)));
}
public byte[] getByteArrayFromInteger(int intValue) {
    ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    wrapped.putInt(intValue);
    return wrapped.array();
}

public static void main (String []args) throws IOException {

    Test app = new Test();

    byte [] b = app.getByteArrayFromInteger(2);
    System.out.println("Length of Byte:\t"+ b.length+ "\n Value: \t"+ getIntegerFromByte(b));
    byte [] byteArr = new byte[]{0,1,0};

    System.out.println("Length of Byte:\t"+ byteArr.length+ "\n Value: \t"+ getIntegerFromByte(byteArr));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could more efficiently use the existing functionality of `BigInteger` as it does all this for you already.

```
public void test() {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  int i = 1234567;
  byte[] ba = BigInteger.valueOf(i).toByteArray();
  int j = new BigInteger(ba).intValue();
  System.out.println("i="+i+" ba="+Arrays.toString(ba)+" j="+j);
}
```

prints

```
i=1234567 ba=[18, -42, -121] j=1234567
```